# Mysql Cant find column

Tags: mysql

I have a simple insert into statement.
But i always get the error code 1054 (Unknow Column)

```
truncate table connect;

insert into auditcheck.connect (﻿ID_Info,namen,First_Name,Last_Name)  
(SELECT ID,CONCAT (First_Name," ",Last_Name),First_Name, Last_Name FROM 
auditcheck.info4c_pep_desk);
```

But the ID column is there! Also in the connect table.

Comment: Seems like some column is missing in you SELECT statement. Can you paste entire error here?

Comment: Could you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for the `connect` and `info4c_pep_desk` tables?